# Ubuntu wifi hotspot not working properly

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, android, hot-spot

I have created wifi hotspot on my Ubuntu 14.04 following [these](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/3-ways-create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu/) instructions. It was working fine. But recently I applied the updates on Ubuntu and since then the hotspot is not working properly. My android device connects to it but cannot visit any website on the internet. I have tried with other android devices, but they did not work either. I can access internet on my laptop (HP probook g3 440) where I have created the hot-spot. I have removed the hot-spot and created it once again just to make sure the settings were not wrong. I also tried creating "access point" type hot-spot ( which I was already using ) with KDE Connection Manager. That did not work either.

[Edit]
Here is a link to the output of wireless-info script: [wireless-info.txt](http://paste.ubuntu.com/17352879/)

PS: [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/194887) is where I found the script.

I am a new user and don't know what information would be useful. But I'll provide the information necessary to solve this issue. Please help me fix the problem.

Comment: Download [this script](http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/522934) and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/786088/edit) your question to include a link to the pastebin output. This way people can have an overview.

Comment: @Videonauth Thanks for the suggestion. I have added the link you asked for.